# How to add a custom TPL on whmcs cart

Tags: whmcs

We are trying to add a new .TPL file inside our Cart Template, we already did everything but when we try acessing:

site.com/cart?a=newfile

It does not work, is there any way to make WHMCS see the new file as part of the template in question?

I trying to create a custom register page to my template.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to create a custom registration page, I suggest you to continue with whmcs default templates instead of creating your own template.

In your custom registration page :

```
-if you want to customize the style, 
you can do that by just editing css and html within viewcart.tpl.

-if you want to addcustom field and inputs into your custom registration form, 
using in Admin area of whmcs Setup-> Custom Client Fields section,
you can add various of inputs with validation.

 -if you want to some action on the registration event, 
use this hook to catch the event and take your action, 
it will fire whenever someone registers from your website :
```

http://docs.whmcs.com/Hooks:ClientAreaRegister